# godot 4, when print vec3(0.5, 0.0, 0.0) on shader, the result is 0.7373

Tags: godot

[image]

I am sorry for my poor english.

i am learning godot.

when i set color vec3(0.5, 0.0, 0.0), the result is vec3(0.7373, 0.0, 0.0).

i want to get vec3(0.5, 0.0, 0.0) for shader debugging. how can i get from godot setting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Mobile and Forward + render backends are using "linear" output, but the Compatibility render backend is using sRGB output. You can check the build-in `OUTPUT_IS_SRGB` in the shader to confirm.

Second, the value you use in your vector would not be converted correctly to the color space. So I get `0.737` on the Mobile and Forward + and render backends unless you do this:

```
shader_type spatial;
render_mode blend_mix, unshaded;

uniform vec4 color:source_color = vec4(0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

void fragment() {
    ALBEDO = color.rgb; 
}
```

Here the `source_color` tells Godot to make the conversion.

With that I'm getting `0.498` in the Mobile and Forward + and render backends.

And what about the Compatibility backend? With it I get `0.502`. regardless.

**Note**: I'm reading the values from the screen, due to a tool limitation, I get only three significant digits. *I believe instead of `0.498` the value would be `0.49804`, and instead of `0.502` the value would be `0.50196`, and of course `0.737` would be `0.7373`.* Also tonemapping and color correction affect this approach of reading the colors, I don't know if they affect yours.